# What is libgio and how can I update my library?

Tags: terminal, macports, open-source

I downloaded a plugin for gimp, but when I execute this, I get:
Reason: Incompatible library version: gmic_gimp requires version 4201.0.0 or later, but libgio-2.0.0.dylib provides version 4001.0.0

But does anyone know what libgio stands for?

I know it is a library file, but I don't know how to upgrade my library version

Comment: Did you update your GIMP to the latest version?

Comment: yes i have the latest version